Which model should I use to run K means clustering in h2o.ai?
I am using h2o.ai and a sample credit card dataset to run kmeans clustering.
Which model should I use to run K means clustering in h2o.ai?
I chose Unsupervised learning. There are 2 options with Kmeans as name - Kmeans and Kmeans Freq. Can I use one of these? I tried Kmeans but the model did not run.
I tried Kmeans but model did not run.

If you want to use K-means, here is the documentation on how to train a model: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/k-means.html.
Please share your code and more information about your environment settings so we can help you more.
